# Opening and ending tag mismatch - Xcode Storyboard error

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

After a merge conflict I needed to delete some characters which were added in different files, after I've done this I'm getting this error:

Line 621: Opening and ending tag mismatch: textView line 557 and subviews

Line 557:

```
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0L0-L4-EMJ" userLabel="Job Text View" customClass="RoundText" customModule="Arvice" customModuleProvider="target">
```

Line 621:

```
</subviews>
```

Complete of Code for Lines between 557-621:

```
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0L0-L4-EMJ" userLabel="Job Text View" customClass="RoundText" customModule="Arvice" customModuleProvider="target">
<rect key="frame" x="16" y="372" width="343" height="225"/>
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0L0-L4-EMJ" userLabel="Job Text View" customClass="RoundText" customModule="Arvice" customModuleProvider="target">
<rect key="frame" x="16" y="128" width="343" height="325"/>
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43529411759999997" green="0.4431372549" blue="0.47450980390000003" alpha="0.75296982020547942" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
<constraints>
<constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="225" id="VOt-bF-NX1"/>
</constraints>
<color key="textColor" red="1" green="0.96078431369999995" blue="0.019607843140000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Brandish" family="Brandish" pointSize="18"/>
<textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="color" keyPath="borderColor">
<color key="value" red="1" green="0.96078431369999995" blue="0.019607843140000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="cornerRadius">
<real key="value" value="30"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
</textView>
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="grV-x2-o7U" customClass="CustomizableButton" customModule="Arvice" customModuleProvider="target">
<rect key="frame" x="16" y="611" width="343" height="40"/>
<rect key="frame" x="16" y="392" width="343" height="30"/>
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43529411759999997" green="0.4431372549" blue="0.47450980390000003" alpha="0.75296982020000003" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
<constraints>
<constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="en1-xh-J1M"/>
</constraints>
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Brandish" family="Brandish" pointSize="18"/>
<state key="normal" title="Add "/>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="cornerRadius">
<real key="value" value="15"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<connections>
<action selector="postPressed:" destination="ZTf-cm-rjD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="gEw-Za-Xl5"/>
</connections>
</button>
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XAx-Sp-9p1" customClass="GADBannerView">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="22"/>
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
</view>
<imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" misplaced="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GVF-qY-rRW">
<rect key="frame" x="99" y="189" width="176" height="175"/>
</imageView>
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tOi-sI-3OX" customClass="RoundLabel" customModule="Arvice" customModuleProvider="target">
<rect key="frame" x="69" y="136" width="290" height="45"/>
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43529411759999997" green="0.4431372549" blue="0.47450980390000003" alpha="0.75296982020000003" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
<nil key="textColor"/>
<nil key="highlightedColor"/>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="cornerRadius">
<real key="value" value="15"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
</label>
<imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tfM-0s-pL1">
<rect key="frame" x="16" y="136" width="45" height="45"/>
<constraints>
<constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="45" id="Tnf-xp-PXp"/>
<constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="45" id="vEc-bG-e1e"/>
</constraints>
</imageView>
</subviews>
```

Comment: What's the question? Your storyboard must be correct XML file and any end tag must match the corresponding start tag.

Comment: How can I solve this error? What do I need to add?? I tried to add <subviews> in Line 557 but through the error is the same just with a line after, which means the error get shown on line 558 and 622 then....

Comment: It's impossible to exactly answer this question without full storyboard code. But I would suggest that your `textView` tag isn't closed between lines 557 and 621.

Comment: It is closed in line 576 - If you want I can add the complete code here

Comment: If YOU WANT, you can add it here :)

Comment: Done it - Just needed some time to display it like this instead of in one line :)

Comment: I guess better to restore storyboard into the previous commit than apply changes over it by XCode.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your have two `textView` tags with the same `id="0L0-L4-EMJ"` but only one end tag. Looks like merge issue.